# Regex extract the first file name

Tags: regex, file, url, expression, extract

I want to extract the first file name from this url: 
Endless_Curse_-_CE_v1.0.zip

[URL=https://google.com/fjhbqp5o5w06/Endless_Curse_-_CE_v1.0.zip]Endless Curse - CE v1.0.zip - 10.4 MB[/URL]

Comment: Regex is not a programming language. Do you have a particular language in mind for this? Each of them supports varying regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*\/)([^\/]*)(\].*\[.*\])
```

the second group will be your filename : http://regex101.com/r/ehU7Ci/1

```
(.*\/)([^/]*)\](.*\[\/URL\])
```

This matches your file name as group 2 in https://regexr.com/3nu8j

Comment: I just tried, it works in notepad++
Do a search and replace (.*\/)([^\/]*)(\].*\[.*\]) with /2, that will give you the filename

Comment: The link that you provided is very nice! Great resource.Thank you